# Emails rendered in dark theme randomly switch to light theme

Tags: mail.app

MacOS 12.0.1, Mail.app version 15.0.

When viewing a message, occasionally I will see the message contents displayed with a dark theme. Then, if I come back to view the same message, it has a light theme. My system is set to "dark theme" and is not set to change over the course of a day or anything like that.

Here are 2 screenshots taken seconds apart, the **only thing** I did was briefly select the next message and then select this message again:

[image]

[image]

This seems like a rendering bug. Does anyone know if there's a fix?